# Получение директории из argv

Tags: c++

В `argv[0]` находится полный путь до до исполняемого файла, а как получить директорию, в которой находится файл?

Comment: для каждой платформы свой способ определения директории, вам для какой ?

Comment: Платформа OS Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, таким способом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    std::string argv_str = argv[0];

    std::string base = argv_str.substr(0, argv_str.find_last_of("\\"));

    std::cout << base << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Под виндоус символ разделителя пути может зависеть от национальных настроек. (Привет Корее!) Даже под русским windows argv[0], может содержать "слеши не в ту строну", например запустите свою программу командой `./test.exe` из-под far.

Comment: @Chorkov ну для таких слешей аналогично можно сделать , суть не в этом вобще

Answer (score 0):

Позиционироваться в конец строки, двигаясь в ней указателем в обратном направлении найти первое от конца вхождение символа / (или \ для Windows - важно в отладчике проверить какой символ записался). Двигаясь в сторону начала найдем второе от конца вхождение символа. Директория будет между этими указателями (с точностью до того, на что показывает указатель).